# How to debug remote-cache write failures?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, bazel

We're using Bazel (via Bazelisk) and set up a [GCS bucket remote cache as documented](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/remote-caching.html#google-cloud-storage). However when we run, it seems we regularly get `BulkTransferExecption`s during the Remote Cache writing phase:

```
>  bazel build //... --sandbox_debug --verbose_failures                                                       
INFO: Invocation ID: fba91f67-788f-47cc-be4e-24f92ed11301
INFO: Analyzed 25 targets (74 packages loaded, 3245 targets configured).
INFO: Found 25 targets...
WARNING: Writing to Remote Cache:
BulkTransferException
INFO: Elapsed time: 17.115s, Critical Path: 15.47s
INFO: 16 processes: 16 worker. 
INFO: Build completed successfully, 39 total actions
```

As far as I can tell, I have the appropriate access ([Storage Object Admin](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles)).

I've been trying to get more information around that specific exception, but I've been unable to.

And if the bucket wasn't working, I'd expect an exception when reading from the cache: I'd seen such things when attempting other URLs to reach the bucket, such as domain `storage.cloud.google.com` instead of `storage.googleapis.com`.

Any and all advice to help debug what's going on here is welcome! The [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/remote-caching-debug.html) is sparse on what to happen *if* you get exceptions, and as far as I can tell no results are uploading so no caching is actually occurring.

**Update** *2020/07/09*

For some unknown reason, when we moved from one bucket to a more permanent planned on, it stopped occurring. So things work for us, and as far as we can tell the buckets were the same, so we don't know why it was failing initially.

Comment: This seems to be related to some Bazel Remote caching [issues](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/11473) .  It maybe more productive to get help from Bazel support or in Bazel dedicated forums.

Comment: My team (on GCP Compute) needed to grant a Storage [access scope](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes) (e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write`, see [full list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/instances/set-scopes)) to our VM's service account user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--verbose_failures`, which will make it print out a longer stack trace. I just had a very similar problem, and figured out that my problem was due to insufficient permissions my service account had on my GCS bucket. I got this more helpful error message with `--verbose_failures`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>REDACTED@REDACTED.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.delete access to REDACTED/cas/REDACTED.</Details></Error>
```

I had to read [the source code the message came from](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/9cc17b52abc6e05212843a9c167553b410528982/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/remote/RemoteSpawnCache.java#L307). I'll try to submit a PR to add this hint to Bazel documentation: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/12945